# Trying to stop my mail merge function from running from Row 2 each time a new row is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

As the title says:

Each time a new row is added, the program is supposed to only run the latest inserted row cos i am using a "Success" string to stop it from running an already merged row.

How do i make sure it only runs or merges newly inserted row not starting from row 2 each time the function runs? Even though i have added in my code "Success" string so that it sees it and skips that row.

Below is my code:

```
var Success = "Success";

function createBulkPDFs()
{
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_jdFncxgkyCuH181MpwyYf25gWrWHMO");

    const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1XAn-1MqH6ER01dnbATLzG9gYWQpFDKfQhUwWHRRcyo");

    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("141fjXWkg0fU3q0u22WUPkJDl82JakTj");

    const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 32).getDisplayValues();

    let errors = [];
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++)
    {
        var check = ss.getRange(i, 33).getValue();

        if (check != Success)
        {
            data.forEach(row =>
            {
                try
                {
                    createPDF(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],
                        row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18],
                        row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27],
                        row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31], row[3], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);

                    errors.push(["Success"]);
                }
                catch (err)
                {
                    errors.push(["Failed"]);
                }
            }); //close forEach

            currentSheet.getRange(2, 33, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);

        }

    }

}

function createPDF(RepTime, Rep_Name, RepIC_No, Ven_Company, RepDs, Ven_Comp_Regis, Ven_Cont_no, Ven_Fax_no, Ven_Add,
    PODquestionone, PODquestiontwo, PODquestionthree, PODquestionfour, PODquestionfive, PODquestionsix, RPOquestionone,
    RPOquestiontwo, RPOquestionthree, RPOquestionfour, RPOquestionfive, RPOquestionsix, RPOquestionseven,
    CIACquestionone, CIACquestiontwo, Prepquestionone, MACCquestionone, MACCquestiontwo, MACCquestionthree,
    MACCquestionfour, WCquestionone, WCquestiontwo, WCquestionthree, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder)
{

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();

    //for(var i = 2; i<=lr; i++){

    var checks = ss.getRange(i, 33).getValue();
    //var che = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();

    //if(checks != ""){

    const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);

    const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());

    const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
    body.replaceText("{RepTime}", RepTime);
    body.replaceText("{RepFullName}", Rep_Name);
    body.replaceText("{RepICNo}", RepIC_No);
    body.replaceText("{VCompany}", Ven_Company);
    body.replaceText("{RepDesig}", RepDs);
    body.replaceText("{VCompanyRegis}", Ven_Comp_Regis);
    body.replaceText("{VConNo}", Ven_Cont_no);
    body.replaceText("{VFaxNo}", Ven_Fax_no);
    body.replaceText("{VAddress}", Ven_Add);

    body.replaceText("{PODQuestionone}", PODquestionone);
    body.replaceText("{PODQuestiontwo}", PODquestiontwo);
    body.replaceText("{PODQuestionthree}", PODquestionthree);
    body.replaceText("{PODQuestionfour}", PODquestionfour);
    body.replaceText("{PODQuestionfive}", PODquestionfive);
    body.replaceText("{PODQuestionsix}", PODquestionsix);

    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionone}", RPOquestionone);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestiontwo}", RPOquestiontwo);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionthree}", RPOquestionthree);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionfour}", RPOquestionfour);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionfive}", RPOquestionfive);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionsix}", RPOquestionsix);
    body.replaceText("{RPOQuestionseven}", RPOquestionseven);

    body.replaceText("{CIACQuestionone}", CIACquestionone);
    body.replaceText("{CIACQuestiontwo}", CIACquestiontwo);

    body.replaceText("{PrepQuestionone}", Prepquestionone);

    body.replaceText("{MACCQuestionone}", MACCquestionone);
    body.replaceText("{MACCQuestiontwo}", MACCquestiontwo);
    body.replaceText("{MACCQuestionthree}", MACCquestionthree);
    body.replaceText("{MACCQuestionfour}", MACCquestionfour);

    body.replaceText("{WCQuestionone}", WCquestionone);
    body.replaceText("{WCQuestiontwo}", WCquestiontwo);
    body.replaceText("{WCQuestionthree}", WCquestionthree);

    tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

    const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

    const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);

    tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

Comment: Is the latest row always inserted at the bottom of the sheet(appended)? Do you run the script manually or on trigger (which?)?

Comment: @ziganotschka, yes, the latest is always inserted at the bottom of the sheet.
The script is run on trigger (Form Submission) but for test, i run it manually to see if it would see the "Success" string and skip that Row and only perform merge for the newly inserted on the last row.. but each test returns same result with earlier rows being recreated and merged again even though it did earlier and set "Success".

Answer (score 0):

A very likely explanation for `if (check != Success)` returning false is that the active sheet `ss`  is not the same like `currentSheet`.

You can avoid this kind of errors by skipping `activate()` and `getActiveSheet()` requests - instead retrieve your sheet of interest always by name.

**Now, if you are using a form submit trigger, you can restructure your code in a more elegant way by using [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).**

- The formSubmit event object allows you to retrieve directly all relevant information related to newest form response - that is the values of the response and the range where this form response was inserted into the sheet.
- You do not need to loop through the whole sheet to find the correct row.

**Sample to be run on formSubmit trigger:**

```js
const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_jdFncxgkyCuH181MpwyYf25gWrWHMO");
const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1XAn-1MqH6ER01dnbATLzG9gYWQpFDKfQhUwWHRRcyo");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("141fjXWkg0fU3q0u22WUPkJDl82JakTj");

function createBulkPDFs(event)
{ 
  let error;
  var row = event.values;
 // have a look at the values:
  Logger.log(row);
  try {
    createPDF(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27],row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31], row[3], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
    error = "Success";
  } catch (err){
     error="Failed";
  }
  var row = event.range.getRow();
  var currentSheet = event.range.getSheet();
  currentSheet.getRange(row, 33).setValue(error);
}
function createPDF(...){
  ...
}
```

> When using funcitons with event objects, keep in mind that they can only be triggered by an event (form submit) - if you try to run the funciton manually - it will error because the event object won't be defined.

Comment: Hi @ ziganotschka, thanks for the explanation. Using the event works like a charm.
For the "Success" string, i used the following:

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");//.activate();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++)
    {
        var check = ss.getRange(i, 33).getValue();
        
        }
        if (check != Success)
        {
            console.log(check);
            let errors = [];
It still doesn't skip previously set Success row.

Comment: Here is the link to my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MpQ54d8OCV1YM7rMP5lfceI3jCiUF5pkACdAZFb8kLM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the problem is that you your `if` statement is not inside the `for` loop. try the following: `for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    var check = ss.getRange(i, 33).getValue(); 
    console.log(ss.getRange(i, 33).getA1Notation());
    console.log(check);
    if (check != Success) { 
      console.log("check is not success"); 
    }
  }`

Comment: Thanks.

I just tried. but still having the same issue.

Here is the log:
[20-10-01 16:39:39:941 HKT] AG2
[20-10-01 16:39:39:943 HKT] Success
[20-10-01 16:39:39:953 HKT] AG3
[20-10-01 16:39:39:955 HKT] 
[20-10-01 16:39:39:957 HKT] check is not success

Comment: This sounds correct to me - after all the cell `AG2` of your sample sheet contains the value `Success` while the cell `AG3` does not.

Comment: Thanks again.. actually what happens is that the success gets appended to AG1 and AG2.. in other words, it actually over writes the success in AG1.. meaning my drive gets populated with duplicates cos it doesnt skip a row that has Success already. but recreates all rows..

Comment: That's becasue of the line `currentSheet.getRange(2, 33, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);`  -you set the values to a static and not dynamic range. This is why I proposed you to retrieve the newly added row dynamically with the event object:  `var row = event.range.getRow(); currentSheet.getRange(row, 33).setValue(error);`

Comment: Okay.. many thanks. So i guess there is no way of retrieving it dynamically without an event object..

Thanks again :)

Comment: It's certainly possible even if not very elegant. 1.option:  New submissions always go to the last row (unless you have a filter function on the sheet), so you can simply retrieve the last row. 2. option: onForm submit the newly  inserted row becomes the active one, so you can define `var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();` 3. Option (not recommended): You can fix your current code querying for "Success#. Here the problem is that you overwrite the whole range with `currentSheet.getRange(2, 33, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);` in each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks,

I tried this:
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();

const data = currentSheet.getRange(row, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 32).getDisplayValues();

replaced this - //currentSheet.getRange(2, 33, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);

with - ss.getRange(i,33).setValue(errors);

It returned the correct row just that it merged 4 extra copies.

Comment: I assume you are still using the for loop iterating multiple times? This is why repeat your request multiple times.

Comment: Hi, actually the data is populated by me and not from a form.

So basically i run a function to grab the contents of the sheet.

Comment: var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getLastRow();
   
    
const data = currentSheet.getRange(row, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 32).getDisplayValues();
- I noticed that this const data is actually whats causing the issue.
When the program runs, it makes copies of the merge file.